# Where is the famous 'Papageno, Papagena duet' located in Mozart's opera 'Die Zauberflöte (The Magic Flute)'?

Tags: mozart, opera

Ah, it's good there is a place to ask this kind of question.
I was looking for the location of the famous [Papagena/Papageno](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=87UE2GC5db0) song from the 'Die Zauberflöte' score but couldn't find it. Where is this song located in the opera?

Comment: Do you mean the one in the film Amadeus where they sing "pa, pa, pa?" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magic_Flute#Some_musical_numbers

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a better fit for Music Fans section of Stack Exchange.

Comment: Follow the score while listening to/watching the opera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the Finale. In the Dover edition that's p.202, in another edition probably about 20 pages before the end of the opera.

Comment: https://imslp.org/wiki/Die_Zauberfl%C3%B6te,_K.620_(Mozart,_Wolfgang_Amadeus) Dover edition on that page, Breitkopt ed. at p. 201.

Comment: Oh, I have also found in the score. Thank you!